# How to debug an elastic4s failure?

Tags: elastic4s

I have some elastic4s code which previously index documents successfully.  Now, new documents aren't showing up.

How can I a) see the query sent to elasticsearch by elastic4s and b) see the response given, so that I can debug the indexing?

Comment: afaik elastic4s uses Java API undercover, so you can't debug it easily (except debugging in the real sense of the word, i.e. have a breakpoint just before you send the query and inspect it). But you can look into the logs of your elasticsearch server and see what it's getting. Also you can emulate the query which you think you are sending, using a tool like Sense plugin or even cURL and see if anything comes back.

Comment: Have you changed version of elastic4s or elasticsearch server ?

Answer (score 3):

In Elastic4s 1.6.2 you can use the show typeclass on a number of requests to get the JSON equivilent for debugging / easy testing in a REST client.

It's pretty straightforward.

```
val req = search in "index" / "type" query "kate bush"
logger.debug(s"Search request ${req.show}")
```

The `.show` method will render JSON output. It works on most of the request types.

Answer (score 2):

In answer to your first question about seeing the request sent to elasticsearch: I fumbled over this, too, and found insight in the unit tests. Look at `IndexDslTest` and `SearchDslTest`. The various `*Request` classes have a `_builder` that generates the query as JSON. Try this to see what's being sent to elasticsearch:

```
val req = index into ...
println(req._builder.toString)
```

Comment: We should probably add this is a debug option in the elastic4s client.

Answer (score 0):

As @Ashalynd said in the comment you can use sense tool in order to try to figure out the problem.

Also i think you should use slow logging  in order to figure the issue.

Check this article how to set the logging configuration in the **logging.yml** file.

*very important is to turn the debug off after you figure out things because its slow things down. (slow logging :))

[slow logging](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/index-modules-slowlog.html)